# Cannot assign "[{'id': '2'}]": "Model .field" must be a "ForeignKey" instance

Tags: python, angularjs, django

I have two model BAI and EMT. BMI has a CharField called country, in my EMT model i have country_name field where i am passing as foreignkey of BMT, Now when i am trying to create a new EMT i am getting this error:

```
Cannot assign "[{'id': '2'}]": "EMT.country" must be a "BAI" instance.
```

**my models**

```
### Country Related Model ###
class BAI(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    capital = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.country

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_country_banner_and_information'
        ordering = ['id']



### Country Export Related Model ###
class EMT(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        BannerandInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    year = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Export')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'app_emt'
        ordering = ['id']
```

**my views**

```
@csrf_exempt
def emt(request, id=None):
    if request.user.profile.role == '2':
        if request.method == 'GET':
            if id is not None:
                try:
                    offer = EMT.objects.get(id=id)
                    data = {
                        'country': '',
                        'year': '',
                    }
                    
                except Exception:
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = json.loads(request.body)
            if id is not None:
                try:
                    existInfo = EMT.objects.get(
                        id=id,
                    )
                    existInfo.country=data.get('country', None)
                    existInfo.year=data.get('year', None)
                    try:
                        existInfo.save()
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 1}), content_type='application/json')
                        
                    except IntegrityError as e:
                        err = e.args[1]
                        err = err.replace(" for key 'email'", " as 'Email'").replace(" for key 'business_phone'", " as 'Business Phone'").replace(" for key 'username'", " as 'Username'")
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0, "error": err}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
                except Exception:
                    try:
                        newInfo = EMT.objects.create(
                            country=data.get('country', None),
                            year=data.get('year', None),
                            
                        )
                        
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 1}), content_type='application/json')
                        
                    except IntegrityError as e:
                        err = e.args[1]
                        err = err.replace(" for key 'email'", " as 'Email'").replace(" for key 'business_phone'", " as 'Business Phone'").replace(" for key 'username'", " as 'Username'")
                        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0, "error": err}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
        elif request.method == 'DELETE':
            if id is not None:
                try:
                    existInfo = EMT.objects.get(
                        id=id,
                        
                    )
                    existInfo.is_deleted=1
                    existInfo.save()
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 1}), content_type='application/json')
                except Exception:
                    return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
            else:
                return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=401)
        else:
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=403)
        
    else:
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({"status": 0}), content_type='application/json', status=403)
```

I am pretty new to django as well as angularjs so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Because `country` is a ForeignKey on the EMT model, when you create an EMT object, that field needs to be more than just an id.

Something like this:

```
country = BAI.objects.get(id=data.get('country'))
newInfo = EMT.objects.create(
    country=country,
    year=data.get('year', None),                 
)
```

Also, it looks like your ForeignKey is set up wrong.

```
country = models.ForeignKey(
    BannerandInformation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Should `BannerandInformation` be `BAI` instead?